# Understanding java 8 lambda expressions used to define Spring Security beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, lambda, java-8

```
@Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
        return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
```

How to understand this `(request, response, authException) ->`, Where did it find all these 3 variables? there are not in class field.

And what is it  `->` ?

Comment: Read something about dependency injection and java 8

Comment: Welcome to Java 8. It's called a lambda expression. Java 8 is out for a few years now, so you'll find a whole bunch of tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AuthenticationEntryPoint` is a functional interface (a interface containing only one public method: `commence`). Functional interfaces implementations can be created using Java Lambda expressions.

In a pre java 8 programming style you could use an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
    AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    };
    return entryPoint;
}
```

Here we create an `AuthenticationEntryPoint` anonymous class in which we implement the behaviour of `AuthenticationEntryPoint.commence()`.

Java 8 lambda expressions provide syntactic sugar to reduce the code to just:

```
return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```

`request, response, authException` will be provided to the method when called.

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html